# Sometimes after Windows startup and user login, not all 'autorun' applications are started. Why?

Tags: windows, boot, autorun

Did you ever experience the same? After you turn on (or reboot) your Windows PC, in about 1 of 10 times it happens that **about 2/3 of programs designed/assigned to be launched automatically** (either on system startup or after login of the user) **won't launch at all.**

You can most easily spot this problem by looking into system tray: there are only a few icons there, most of usual program icons are missing. Then you can see in *Task manager* that those applications are not running so it is not only about missing tray icons.

In this situation, **fastest workaround is just another restart of PC** and then everything goes normally. But I would like to know what is causing this and **whether this can be fixed.** It appears to be quite random issue, but happening relatively frequently.

I have seen this on various Windows 7 machines (2-3 PC's), now it happens also on my Windows 8 PC. Maybe Windows XP was affected, too, but I don't rembemer.

Programs omitted from start include antivirus, AutoHotKey, screenshot tool, password manager, ... just anything. Even my custom scheduled task designed to launch 30 seconds after user login does not start.

This is related only to first login following Windows startup. If startup was successful (all programs launched), this cannot happen to second or third user who logged into Windows.

Comment: How many items are starting?

Comment: @CharlieRB - I would say about 15 more compared to a fresh installed Windows Lenovo PC. (Mentioning 'Lenovo' points to some system tools and bloatware added by vendor.) Of course in absolute numbers (see **Everything** tab in [autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) tool, it is up to 170 items. But I guess fresh installed Windows Lenovo PC has about 150 items there. But I have seen this startup issue appear also on PC's of other brands – like Dell – so I think this is not dependent on manufacturer.